# Parsing a Date Like "Wednesday 13th January 2010" with .NET

Tags: c#, datetime

How can I convert the following strings to a System.DateTime object?

Wednesday 13th January 2010
Thursday 21st January 2010
Wednesday 3rd February 2010

Normally something like the following would do it

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dddd d MMMM yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

but this doesn't work because of the 'th', 'st' or 'rd' in the string

*Update*

It appears that DateTime [doesn't support formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) the 'th', 'st', 'rd' etc so they need to be stripped before parsing. Rubens Farias provides a nice regular expression below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about strip them?

```
string value = "Wednesday 13th January 2010";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
    Regex.Replace(value, @"(\w+ \d+)\w+ (\w+ \d+)", "$1 $2"),
    "dddd d MMMM yyyy", 
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, 
    DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: Okay, so your Regex appears to be working fine and stripping out the 'th', 'st' etc but for some reason the DateTime parsing is still failing. Am I missing something? Culture maybe? Does this work for you?

Comment: Note that the formatter for the full day name in .NET is `dddd`, lowercase. I've edited your answer to reflect this, Rubens.

Comment: Works great now and a nice solution

Comment: Note that The 'dd' in the format should be a single 'd', "dddd d MMMM yyyy", otherwise single digit dates fail. I haven't got the rep to edit it.

Comment: This regex expression works if there's no commas in the date. It fails for "Wednesday, January 13th, 2010" but works fine for "Wednesday Januarary 13th 2010". Any regex experts willing to fix that?

Comment: That isn't a 'fix', but a new requirement: `"(\w+),? (\w+) (\d+)\w+,? (\d+)", "$1 $3 $2 $4"`

Answer (score 4):

Another approach.

```
string sDate = "Wednesday 13th January 2010";
string[] sFields = sDate.Split (' ');
string day = sFields[1].Substring (0, (sFields[1].Length - 2));
DateTime date = new DateTime (sFields[3], sFields[2], day);
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative using escape characters for handling (`st`, `nd`, `rd`, and `th`) without stripping them before the call of `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
string dtstr = "Saturday 23rd January 2016";
DateTime dt;
string[] formats = new string[] { 
    "dddd d\\s\\t MMMM yyyy", "dddd d\\n\\d MMMM yyyy",
    "dddd d\\r\\d MMMM yyyy", "dddd d\\t\\h MMMM yyyy" };
bool result = DateTime.TryParseExact(dtstr, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Comment: much cleaner solution!

Comment: @NielsBosma thanks! :) I am glad that you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Where does "th", "st","nd" or "rd" appear below?

- mo**nd**ay
- tuesday
- wednesday
- **th**ursday
- friday
- satu**rd**ay
- su**nd**ay
- january
- february
- march
- april
- may
- june
- july
- augu**st**
- september
- october
- november
- december

However you know those 4 will always be followed by a space. So unless I've missed something, a simple

```
value = value.Replace("August","Augus").Replace("nd ","").Replace("st ","").Replace("nd ","").Replace("rd ","").Replace("Augus","August");
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(value,"DDDD dd MMMM yyyy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

No credit to me but this looks interesting for general DataTime parsing: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/date_time_parser_cs.aspx?msg=3299749

Answer (score 0):

I remembered [this post on using MGrammar](http://www.infoq.com/articles/natural-language-date-dsl-oslo) to parse a lot of different ways to express dates and times. It doesn't exactly answer your question, but it might serve as a useful base depending on what your ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Kenny's approach, I added some code to pass integers to the DateTime variable...

```
string sDate = "Wednesday 13th January 2010";
string[] dateSplit = sDate.Split (' ');
string day = dateSplit[1].Substring(0, dateSplit[1].Length - 2);
int monthInDigit = DateTime.ParseExact(dateSplit[3], "MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Month;
DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(year), monthInDigit, day);
```