# Convert to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to convert a string to a DateTime object. My string will be in this format- "18th Jul 2016" (the date can change). Obviously, .Net does not take this as a valid date format. Is there any easy way to convert this without using any third party library?

Comment: Did you check out the [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2058639/447156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `String.Replace` since it could be a problem is the current culture's month-name contains the strings you're going to replace.

Instead you could remove this part from the string:

```
string input = "18th Jul 2016";
string[] token = input.Split();  // split by space, result is a string[] with three tokens
token[0] = new string(token[0].TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
input = String.Join(" ", token);
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd MMM yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date is: " + dt.ToLongDateString());
}
```

If you pass `null` as `IFormatProvider` to [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) the current culture's datetimeformat is used. If you want to force english names you can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Better than `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

Comment: @Ghasan: not better but _correct_ when you want to force english names ;) Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

```
string dateStr = "18th Jul 2016";
dateStr = dateStr.Replace("th", "").Replace("st", "").Replace("rd", "").Replace("nd", "");

DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateStr, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, 
                                                  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out date))
{

}
else
{
    // error
}
```

Comment: The replace approach is vulnerable to localization issues, maybe some countries use `st`, `nd`, `th` or `rd` in the name of the month.

Comment: This solution looks fine as my code is supposed to run on an internal machine where we do not expect any localization issues and the inputs will always be in this format. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a fudge but

```
string result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(dt, "[st|th|nd|rd]{2} ", " ", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(result);
```

I included the space so it doesnt try editing the months.. I did start out with [0-9]{1,2} and replacing it with the number, but that seemed overkill

Answer (score 0):

```
string dateString = "18th Jul 2016";
dateString = Regex.Replace(dateString, @"^(\d{2})(st|nd|rd|th)", "$1");
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```